# ClassNotFoundException org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver

Tags: java, maven, junit, jboss, jboss-arquillian

When I run my Arquillian tests I get error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebDriver;   at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2570)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1903)    at
>   org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.getSortedDeclaredFields(TestClass.java:77)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.scanAnnotatedMembers(TestClass.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.(TestClass.java:57)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.createTestClass(ParentRunner.java:88)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.(ParentRunner.java:83)  at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
>     at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.(Arquillian.java:55)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
>     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)   at
>   org.jboss.arquillian.junit.container.JUnitTestRunner.execute(JUnitTestRunner.java:66)
>     at
>   org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.executeTest(ServletTestRunner.java:159)
>     at
>   org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.execute(ServletTestRunner.java:125)
>     at
>   org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.doGet(ServletTestRunner.java:89)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver from
>   [Module "deployment.sp.war:main" from Service Module Loader]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134)
>     ... 56 more

My pom.xml:

> ```
> <!--Tests-->
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>junit</groupId>
>   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>   <version>${version.junit}</version>
>   <scope>test</scope>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
>   <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
>   <scope>test</scope>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
>   <artifactId>arquillian-drone-webdriver-depchain</artifactId>
>   <type>pom</type>
>   <scope>test</scope>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>xerces</groupId>
>   <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
>   <version>2.11.0</version>
>   <scope>test</scope>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
>   <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded</artifactId>
>   <version>8.1.0.Final</version>
>   <scope>test</scope>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
>   <artifactId>arquillian-angularjs-graphene</artifactId>
>   <version>1.2.0.Alpha1</version>
>   <type>pom</type>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
>   <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain</artifactId>
>   <version>${version.shrinkwrap.resolvers}</version>
>   <scope>test</scope>
>   <type>pom</type>
> </dependency>
> ```

I package test web archive as follow:

```
public class Deployments {
  public static Archive createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(MavenImporter.class)
        .loadPomFromFile("/Users/alekspo/Documents/Development/Java/WildFly/sp/pom.xml")
        .importBuildOutput().as(WebArchive.class);
  }
}
```

Any idea why I got such NoClassDefFound error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced exactly the same problem today. It's definitely not a dependency problem. The stack trace already hints that Arquillian is trying to run the Drone test in the server itself instead of acting as client. This is in first place strange as we actually want to run it as client. How to do that is described in Arquillian's guide [Functional Testing using Drone and Graphene](http://arquillian.org/guides/functional_testing_using_graphene/):

> #### Enabling Client Mode
>
> How do you activate client mode? Quite simply. You either mark a deployment as non-testable, meaning Arquillian will not enrich the archive, or you can mark a specified method with the annotation `@RunAsClient`.

In other words, you need either

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class Test {

    @Deployment(testable = false)
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        // ...
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

or

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class Test {

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        // ...
    }

    @Test
    @RunAsClient
    public void test() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

This has at least solved your problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add maven dependency for selenium.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.42.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Not helped. Error steel persists.
selenium-java included in this dependency
`<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
  <artifactId>arquillian-drone-webdriver-depchain</artifactId>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>`